# Objective C: Display log in NSLabel or NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, console, nstextfield, nslog

Is there a way to display the console log (where all the NSLogs are displayed) continuously in an NSLabel or a continuously scrolling NSTextField?

There are important messages in the console I would like to print that are sent by the machine (not the NSLogs I call myself), that's why I would like to do this.

Comment: it is certainly possible.. for implementation, use ur imagination...!!

Comment: Instead of using NSLog, just created a simple function that adds text towards your own NSTextField.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Other than that?

Comment: I edited the question, it's not the NSLogs I want, but the other stuff beside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are trying to get the info outside of xcode, you could always launch it from terminal to see what it spits out.

1. Open Terminal.app
2. type /path/to/your.app/Contents/MacOS/your

It will display NSLogs and errors that are spit out.